# convert an string with multiple words to an array of char

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Imagine I have the following string:

```
char input[] = "this is an example";
```

I want to take this string and make each word an entry in an array,
how could I get this into an array like this:

```
char inputArray[] = {"this","is","an","example"};
```

Comment: You cannot do that because each element of `char inputArray[]` is type `char` and it cannot store strings nor pointers to strings.

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because clearly a write my code request, not a question. Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, i always seek to improve myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you do not know exactly what you want or you want the following:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char input[] = "this is an example";

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( char *p = input; *p;  )
    {
        while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

        if ( *p )
        {
            ++n;
            while ( *p && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
        }
    }

    char * inputArray[n];

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( char *p = strtok( input, " \t" ); p != NULL; p = strtok( NULL, " \t" ) ) inputArray[i++] = p;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( inputArray[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
this
is
an
example
```

Comment: That is what i wanted, i just have a hard time phrasing questions :-)

Comment: @Peterverleg Take into account that the original array is changed by the function strtok. It inserted zero-characters in the string to split it in words..

Comment: Maybe rather than traversing the input string twice it would be better to allocate space for `inputArray` as needed, inside the loop with the `strtok()` call.

Comment: @pmg When the memory will be reallocated each time in a loop.

Comment: I have a thing with VLA's. They tend to fail at the worst time (when the client tries a 2M long string). It takes a bit more management (keeping two counts of elements) to grow the array as needed for better safety.